# Deriving the type an associative array of functions

Tags: typescript

I want the caller of a function to supply an associative array of functions.
My function will return a new associative array of functions with the same keys, the same return types, but the functions will take a different argument to that of the functions in the map passed into the function.

I can't figure out how to create the return type of this function.

My attempt so far is along the lines of:

```
type FunctionMap<A> = {
    [functionName: string]: <R>(a: A) => R
}

type B = {};
const b: B = {};

const FunctionMapArg: FunctionMap<B> = {
    getA: b => 1,
    getB: b => "two"
};

type TypeOfFunctionMapArg = typeof FunctionMapArg;


type ReturnedFunctionMap<T extends TypeOfFunctionMapArg> = {
    [P in keyof T]: () => ???; // using Typescript 2.6
//    [P in keyof T]: () => ReturnType<T[P]); // using Typescript 2.8
}
```

However this is failing at pretty much the first step - I can't even declare the `FunctionMapArg` constant. I'm getting the following error from the compiler:

```
Type '{ getA: <R>(a: any) => number; getB: <R>(a: any) => string; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionMap<any>'.
Property 'getA' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '<R>(a: any) => number' is not assignable to type '<R>(a: any) => R'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'R'.
```

Could somebody please put me in the right direction? Ideally I'm looking for a solution that works with Typescript 2.6.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "but a different (single) argument"?

Comment: That's no <strike>moon</strike> array...

Comment: Thanks @andrew, jcalz has provided a great answer for me. Basically the functions in the resulting map need to take a different argument to that in the original map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want the arguments of the input and output functions to be, so this is a guess.  The main idea is to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to represent the transformation you want to achieve.  (Both of those features should work in TypeScript 2.6.)  For example, let's say your input functions look like this:

```
type B = {
  // input function argument type here
};

const functionMapArg = {
  getA: (b: B) => 1,
  getB: (b: B) => "two"
};

declare const b: B;
const gotA = functionMapArg.getA(b); // number
const gotB = functionMapArg.getB(b); // string
```

Then here's one way you might transform `functionMapArg`:

```
type Functionize<T, A> = { [K in keyof T]: (a: A) => T[K] };
type C = {
  // output function argument type here
};
declare function alterFunctions<T>(fs: Functionize<T, B>): Functionize<T, C>;
```

`Functionize<T, A>` takes a regular object type `T` and produces a mapped type whose keys `K` are the same as those of `T`, and whose values are functions from `A` to `T[K]`.  And `alterFunctions()` takes a `Functionize<T, B>` as input (such as `functionMapArg`), and produces a `Functionize<T, C>` as output... where the TypeScript compiler infers the type `T` for you.  Let's see it work:

```
const alteredFunctions = alterFunctions(functionMapArg);
declare const c: C;
const gotAnotherA = alteredFunctions.getA(c); // number
const gotAnotherB = alteredFunctions.getB(c); // string
```

So `alteredFunctions` is like `functionMapArg` but its methods take an argument of type `C` instead of an argument of type `B`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

Update: if you want to avoid writing the argument type for each function in `functionMapArg`, you can make a helper function which expects an input of type `Functionize<any, B>` and returns the input unchanged, like this:

```
function asFunctionsOfB<F extends Functionize<any, B>>(fs: F): F {
  return fs;
}
```

And that way the compiler will infer the argument type:

```
const functionMapArg = asFunctionsOfB({
  getA: b => 1,
  getB: b => "two"
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks good, and it works :thumbsup: 
Just wondering if there's a way to type `functionMapArg` so that I don't have to specify (b: State) as the argument for each function?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to integrate that into the the alterFunctions signature, i.e.: `alterFunctions<F extends Functionalize<any, B>>(fs: F)`. I wish I could upvote you twice